# Basic theorem of field extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

I am studying the **the basic theorem of field extensions** with *Charles C. Pinter*'s book: *A book of Abstract Algebra*. The very same theorem that is being discussed here: [Example of Basic Theorem of field extensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2272238/example-of-basic-theorem-of-field-extensions).

I am trying to follow the proof in the book but I run into something I don't quite understand or see why is true. Hopefully someone can help me?

The part I am struggling with is where we try to prove that:
$\overline{a}_0 + \overline{a}_1\overline{x} + \cdots + \overline{a}_n\overline{x}^n = J$

where $J$ is the zero coset and: $J + a_0 = \overline{a}_0, \ldots , J + a_n = \overline{a}_n$ and $J + x = \overline{x}$.

In the book it goes:
\begin{align}
\overline{a}_0 + \overline{a}_1\overline{x} + \cdots + \overline{a}_n\overline{x}^n & = (J + a_0) + (J+a_1)(J+x) + \cdots + (J+a_n)(J+x)^n \\
& = (J + a_0) + (J+a_1x)+ \cdots + (J+a_nx^n) \\
& = J + p(x) \\
& = J \quad \quad \quad [\text{because } p(x) \in J]
\end{align}

where $p(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial in the original field.

I guess where I am struggling is how:
$(J+a_1)(J+x) = (J+a_1x)$ and $(J+a_n)(J+x)^n = (J+a_nx^n)$ ?

In advance; thank you :)

Comment: Because $a \mapsto \overline a$ is a [homomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_homomorphism) from $A$ to $A/J$, where $A$ is whatever you mean here (where all your $a_i$ and $x$ live).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It occurs to me that you may be looking at the offending equation
$$
(J+a)(J+b)=(J+ab)
$$
and making too much of it. In particular, how is “$(J+a)(J+b)$” to be understood? To multiply these two cosets, you don’t take all possible products, one factor from $(J+a)$, the other from $(J+b)$; rather, you *choose* one element, say $a_0\in(J+a)$, and one, say $b_0\in(J+b)$, and see what coset $a_0b_0$ belongs to. That will be your product coset.
But notice: I have italicized the word “choose”, so you have to verify that the resulting coset does not depend on your choice.

Accordingly, choose other $a_1\in(J+a)$ and $b_1\in(J+b)$, so that $a_1-a_0\in J$ and $b_1-b_0\in J$. Then
$$
a_1b_1-a_0b_0=a_1(b_1-b_0)+(a_1-a_0)b_0\in J\,,
$$
because the perenthesized quantities are in $J$. Thus $a_0b_0$ and $a_1b_1$ are in the same $J$-coset, and your choice didn’t matter. In particular, the product coset is $(J+ab)$.

(Note: because $p$ is irreducible, it happens that the set of all possible products *is* a coset, equal to the product coset. Not so if $p$ is reducible.)

Comment: Haha yes! Offending is quite the right word for the context :) Thank you @Lubin for the neat structure of the explanation, it is easy to follow. I do wonder though why the terms parentheses being in the coset also makes a_1 + b_0 being in the coset? Also; why you choose the equation a_1*b_1 - a_0*b_0 ? I apologize if there is something obvious I am not seeing.

Comment: Remember: if $c$ is in the coset and $w$ is in the ideal ($J$ in this case), then $c+w$ is in the coset. I was showing that if $a,a'$ are in a particular coset, and if $b,b'$ are in another coset, then $ab$ is in the same coset as $a'b'$.

Comment: Ahh, of course. That makes a lot of sense. Thank you @Lubin !!

Answer (score 0):

Here $J=\langle p(x)\rangle$ is the ideal generated by the underlying irreducible polynomial.

The result basically says that $\bar x = x+J$ is a zero of $p(x)$ which lies in the extension field $F/J$.

Indeed, the computation shows that $p(\bar x)= \bar 0$, with $\bar 0 =J$.